# Can 10-rep users post images?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, images

Whats the deal with posting images? I've just spent a long time composing a nice post with images and stuff, only to be told I can't post images unless my rep is 10, but my rep is 10 (on Stack Overflow)! Maybe you mean rep > 10 not rep >= 10?

Comment: There, now you have 20. Voting to close...

Comment: @Downvoter, yes he has the rep now, but if the message is inaccurate, it's still a bug.

Comment: **update**: since 2013-09-05 New users (< 10 rep) can [post images on any site except for Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User and Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/146318)

Answer (score 6):

Also (besides the ">" or ">=" question), in such a case it's okay just to put in the link to the picture with a short note asking whoever having 2k rep comes by to put the images in. This happens quite often and works well.

This requirement is still in effect on Stack Overflow, although it's been relaxed on most other sites in the network that see less volume of posts and images. If it becomes a problem anywhere, we can turn this back on.

Comment: It is, but the people that don't have the reputation are often new to the site and may not be aware of the ways the site works like this :)