# What site-specific configuration settings are possible, and how have they been implemented by the various communities?

Tags: discussion, site-specific

What features of a stack exchange site - connected to content display and moderation rules - can be decided on and implemented on a per-site basis?

Is there a public, central comparison anywhere of how each community has chosen to set them up?

Comment: I like it, but the "how have they been implemented" part is certainly not quite suitable, you can't keep an up-to-date list of so many settings for so many sites.

Comment: Related: [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/335251)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a little broad, so the best I can offer you is a general rule of when something is *probably* configurable per-site. I want to offer that with a healthy disclaimer:

***Just because we can configure things differently per-site doesn't mean we should or will.***

The following things are common to be *just* a little different from site to site:

- Post processors for text (SoundCloud, MathJax, YouTube support, etc)
- SPAM protection settings and weights (higher traffic sites tend to carry more weight)
- Migration paths
- Off-topic close reasons (mods can change these)
- Small bits of text such as the site name, topic, guidance shown in a few places <sup>1</sup>
- Help center articles (mods can change some of these)
- Blacklists (tag, phrase, etc) coupled with warning lists that show just-in-time help

Other things are *sometimes* changed depending on the volume and needs of a site:

- Required registration in order to ask questions
- Different than usual rep thresholds for certain privileges
- Fine tuning of question block and rolling rate limit algorithms
- SPAM / robot honeypot and other bot-defeating knobs
- Performance tweaks

Everything else remains pretty much the same, with very few exceptions. The goal is to provide a familiar interface to a wide variety of topics and communities - the software being the middle ground.

*Most* settings are established based on the Area 51 proposal and outcome of the private beta period for a site, it's more what a community *shows* than chooses, although they definitely have say in the matter as expressed on their meta site.

This isn't something that we'd really showcase, it's just plumbing, and I'm not going to go into it more - but there's no harm in listing it, so here it is :) This is *not* meant to be exhaustive.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Internationalization makes this interesting, on non-English sites, copy changes are a bit more of a big deal.</sub>

Comment: What about Triage? Is it configurable per site as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard deliberately not mentioned as that is still very much in testing. (But you'll notice, only turned 'on' for Stack Overflow, so that should give you some idea)

Comment: (...And now for Physics as well.)

Answer (score 4):

(I don't know if such a list exists elsewhere. I like the idea and I made this CW so that the list can grow.)

- Syntax highlighting support
- New contributor indicator
- MathJax support

  - `mhchem` extension support
  - Alternate delimiter support (`\$` instead of `$`)
- Migration paths
- Custom community-specific (off-topic) close reasons
- Custom "what to ask" and "what not to ask" posts in Help Center
- Review audits turned on/off
- Warning/help messages when specific tags are used
- Embedded YouTube videos (Arqade, ...)
- Increased number of links allowed in posts from new users (Skeptics)
- Ability of new users to post images (disabled on [some large sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/))
- Number of close votes per day (24 on most sites, 50 on some of the larger ones)
- [Whether the Excavator and Archaeologist badges are available or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330611/how-is-the-recommended-next-badge-determined-exactly#comment1078588_330614)