# Are the rules of all Stack Exchange sites the same?

Tags: support, help-center, rules

Are the rules of all Stack Exchange sites the same?

I see their Help Centers are the same.

Comment: The software is almost the same, but there are a few per-site settings. See here for a list: [What site-specific configuration settings are possible, and how have they been implemented by the various communities?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249719/271946) Also, different sites can have different polices.

Comment: The help centers vary a _tiny_ bit when it comes to what's on / off topic, but the rest of it pretty much applies regardless (especially the account level / how things work entries). I think what you're talking about are _community conventions_, or the particular ways each site does things a tad bit differently.

Answer (score 17):

Our one ***global*** rule is [don't be a jerk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback), but we really like it when you try to actually be *nice*.

As I watch new communities take shape and work out how their topic is going to fit within the confines of our software, someone will inevitably say:

> But SE policy won't permit this

When I read this, I sometimes want to jump in screaming *Hey, look over here, see me? I work at SE, we have no such policy, someone just inferred that based on the rigidity of certain other sites in our network*.

We want communities to be able to do their topic justice *without* having to contort how they go about it to the broadest extent that is possible. To this, we're always open to trying new things, nobody likes a suit of clothes a few sizes too small, no matter how shiny it looks.

Our sites imply a sort of contract with people that find them. If they ask a question on one of our sites:

- It will receive at *least* one or two answers
- Those answers will quickly be evaluated and vetted through an expert peer-review process
- Both things will happen in an amount of time that someone would reasonably expect to wait

As long as that is happening, and the community is actively trying to serve their topic *better than anything else currently serving it*, ***do what you do, we'll try very hard to not get in your way.***

This means you'll need to spend a short amount of time acclimating to how each individual community does things. Pets, Parenting, Network Engineering - the only thing these have in common is that they're endeavors  that people want to get better at doing, and that's the common thread tying them to our software.

We will not run a cheeseburger network, we're not about mindless fun - there's plenty of places on the Internet to get that. We expect that our sites will make the Internet *better* in some way.

As far as participating? Just see the linked [code of conduct](/conduct) and *ask someone* if you're unsure of something. Invest some time in asking *what does this site need?* - the answer to that question is going to be a *big* insight into how each community differs in behavior in subtle ways. If a site is struggling to get questions, for instance, folks would probably prefer that you edit instead of closing whenever possible.

Drop into chat. Say hello, ask folks what's good to read on meta. Look at the top questions - you'll pick up the 'vibe' pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The Help Centers of all Stack Exchange sites are similar, but not completely the same.

In particular, the moderators of each site are able to customize the top section of the main Help Center page, as well as the contents of their on-topic page (titled "What topics can I ask about here?").

For example, on [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com), its [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) links to a [How to Ask a Good Question?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) FAQ from its Meta.

On the [Genealogy & Family History](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com) site, the [equivalent page](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has an extensive explanation of its privacy guidelines.

In general, the Help Center refers to very few *rules*, and provides a lot of guidance.