# Is there somewhere I can find all of Stack Exchange's policies in one place?

Tags: support

Is there some useful reference place which has Stack Exchange's policies in it? I've kind of been using Meta Stack Exchange itself for this purpose, but it would be way better and more reliable if there's a place with *all* of it's policies together.

Comment: What sort of "policies"? [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/21960) might be the best you can get.

Comment: "policies" as in any and all policies. Kind of like a complete users manual for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Don't define a word with itself. What you're thinking of as "policies" is probably different than what I'm thinking of. As for using the software, that's all in the [tour] and the [help]. Questions tagged [meta-tag:faq] are issues that come up all of the time, and the answers to those questions are as canonical as it gets. Remember, as well, that every site is different, so what's okay on one site may be completely off-topic on another; that's why the [help] is customized.

Comment: to clarify, I'm (re)defining "policies" as any and all codes of conduct that apply to all Stack Exchange sites. It looks like FAQ is about as close as it gets.

Comment: Related: [Are the rules of all sites on StackExchange the same?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252338/21960)

Comment: Thanks, that was actually pretty helpful.