# How to add multiple images/photos to a question

Tags: support, images, uploader

I am member at different Stack Exchange communities; especially Signal Processing and Stack Overflow, but one thing I find difficult is that if I want to add/attach more than one photo/image/snapshot with my question, I am not able to do so. Please guide me, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add them one at a time, using the upload link, uploading, and repeating per image. There's no 'bulk' upload option.

I suspect at very low rep levels, the [8 link maximum is in play](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user), but it's slightly unlikely you'd hit that maximum.

Comment: but what if my question needs two images?should i post two different questions?

Comment: No, you use the upload link twice

Comment: but if i use upload link second time,my previous/first image will be overwrited/replaced

Comment: @engr Are you posting from mobile? I have the same when I post on mobile, not sure if it's by design.

Comment: You need to use a different URL for the second image, I was having the same issue but got round it by uploading the images separately with different URLs. If your using the Android App you can use the image upload and attach URL or the standard URL option.

Answer (score 3):

On [some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/295232), new users can't post images at all.

In that case, you can upload them externally (e.g. via https://imgur.com/) and link to the images in your question. If you're lucky, another user with enough reputation will read your question and 'inline' the images.