# Unable to add image to post because of reputation or new user status

Tags: support, images, posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can 10-rep users post images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44675/can-10-rep-users-post-images)

I was trying to post photos (diagram) to clarify the ideas, but I coudn't do that because of the following:

"We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images."

I guess it's 2 reasons:

- You have to be more than 10 reputation points. (Which i have)
- You cannot be a new user. (Which I am)

What do I have to do to become a non-new user? Is it related to time (how much time?) or is it related to reputation (how many points?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is correct. You **don't** have more than 10 reputation points. You have **exactly** 10 reputation points.

Well, now you have 15, with my upvote. I hope you don't mind, I edited [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528145/can-my-ios-app-load-a-xml-file-and-generate-interface-from-the-information-withi) a little.

Comment: hahahaha... Sorry... My bad!

Comment: By the way, now I have 15 reputation posts, and I just posted a photo. It's working normally. Tks a lot.

Comment: No problem about changing that question, feel free. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, @Lyniker.