# Possible bug with new spam user uploading image with just 1 rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, privileges, spam

So Mystical pointed out earlier today [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2146443#2146443) that a spammer was recently able to post a spam image to Meta Stack Exchange in a question, even though (if I recall correctly) the spammer only had 1 reputation:

> How did this spam user manage to get in an image?
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234670/health-insurance

According to [Can 10-rep users post images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44675/can-10-rep-users-post-images), user's cannot upload images until they earn 10 rep.

So is there some kind of bug that allows spammers (or non-spamming regular users) with only 1 rep to upload images?

Comment: Perhaps that only applies to StackOverflow and not to MSE? [Related](http://addyosmani.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/unicorn.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [New users and attaching images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111388/new-users-and-attaching-images)

Comment: Related: [Which SE sites require 10 reputation points to post images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258875/335251)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That post is out of date. We [removed the rep requirement on most sites (except Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Super User)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/146318) a few months ago.

So far this hasn't been an issue and the positive uses (such as new users being able to post screenshots) outweighed the negatives. However, if this becomes a rampant problem on any site, we can turn the reputation requirement back on.

Comment: So was the requirement removed only for images, or was it removed for [other restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) as well, such as only being able to post 2 links, not being able to rapidly post questions and answers, etc?

Comment: Just images. The privilege description you linked to is up-to-date right now.

Comment: "2013-09-05: New users (< 10 rep) can now [post images on any site except for Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User and Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/146318)" Do I find documenting stuff in [Recent feature changes...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/165773) convenient? you bet! :)

Comment: Has this changed again? Because I'm pretty sure <10 rep users can't post images on AU still.. and then, of course, there's [this](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/a-new-startup-from-israel)

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Yeah, it's disabled on AU. Otherwise, no changes.

Comment: We've had a few spambots on PPCG recently that are submitting garbage answers and/or suggested edits just to use the image uploader (and creating a bunch of work for flaggers/reviewers in the process). So far it's only three posts that I've seen (over the course of a couple of days), but it's worth mentioning in case a) it gets worse, or b) they're attacking other exchanges too.